# /stext command not working in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, command-prompt

I have a bat called launch.bat and ChromePass.exe in the same folder.

The bat:

```
chromepass.exe /stext output.txt
```

When executed, all it does is open the program in a new window and does not create the text file.

How can I make it so the program runs silently and actually outputs the text file?

Comment: Have you asked the developer using his feedback link, nirsofer@yahoo.com?

Comment: There should be no new window. This works here `chromepass.exe /stext C:\test\output.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the developer (nirsoft.net) has removed the command-line options from the official releases as they were usually used by viruses to steal passwords from users without them knowing.
Original blog-post: http://blog.nirsoft.net/2014/09/22/command-line-options-removed-from-the-official-release-of-my-password-recovery-tools/

Answer (score 0):

```
call ".\chromepass.exe" /stext .\output.txt
```

or

```
.\chromepass.exe /stext .\output.txt
```

Try one of those in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

try this /stext "readme.txt" it works perfectly on my windows 10

Answer (score -1):

I hope when this code has run, you can get the solution of this problem

```
@echo off

start WireView.exe /stext WireView.txt
```

or 
    @echo off

```
start WireView.exe > WireView.txt
```